# Multiplication of n dimensional skew-symmetric matrix and projection matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem is related to the  [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818187/finding-a-matrix-a-neq-0-such-that-a2-0/1818434#1818434)

I checked that

*if we take any non-zero skew-symetric matrix in 2D and multiply it by a projection matrix for any vector of standard basis we obtain  non-zero matrix $A$ with property $A^2=0$.*

The same was checked by me for **3D and 4D**...

My questions are:

- Is the statement above true for any dimension n?
- If so how to prove it?
- Is it the only method (for $n$-dimension)  of generating similar matrices or can be  devised other general procedure (not equivalent) for n-dimension?

Comment: Think about what such a matrix might look like. What can you say about its rows/columns?

Comment: Any non-zero values are only in one exactly column ? and row $k$ where $k$ is  the number of this column must have only zeros?

Comment: $$S := \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$is skew-symmetric, and $I_2$ is a projection matrix. Let $A:=S I_2 = S$. However, $A^2 = S^2= -I_2 \neq O_2$.

Comment: @amd Oh, now I see what's going on. First we should have any hollow matrix, not exactly skew-symetric (although it is basically equivalent) and we can choose a row or column by left of right multiplication with the projection matrix ( the rest r./c. are 0) Composition of this matrix ensure us that square is 0. Thank you amd for excellent hint.

Comment: @Widawensis You wrote "projection", not "unit".

Comment: @Rodrigo , projection changes the skew-symetric, generally it's equivalent to selecting row or column.(Left/Rigth multiplication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: See addendum for the general case.**

In what follows, let $R(C)$ denote the column space or range of a matrix $C$, let $N(C)$ denote its null space or kernel, and let $r(C) = \dim R(C) = \dim R(C^T)$ denote its rank.

I claim that the best result you can get along these lines is the following:

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $A^2 = 0$ and $r(A) = 1$;
> 2. $A = BP$ for $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ satisfying $B^T = -B$ and $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ satisfying $P^2 = P^T = P$, $r(P)=1$, and $BP \neq 0$;
> 3. $A = vw^T$ for non-zero $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $v^Tw = 0$.

Before continuing with the proof, let me make some comments:

- Your proposed construction, when it does work, is a special case of 2., but you do need to be careful: if
  $$
   B = \begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \quad P = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix},
  $$
  then $BP = 0$ precisely because $P = e_3 e_3^T$ and $Be_3 = 0$.
- A correct version of the result you're seem to be after is that 1. and 2. are equivalent; however, the actual heart of the matter is that 1. and 3. are equivalent.
- In 1., the condition $r(A) = 1$, which is automatic for non-zero $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ with $A^2 = 0$, is non-trivial for larger square matrices $A$ with $A^2 = 0$, as is demonstrated by the $4 \times 4$ matrix
  $$
   A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
  $$
  which is a rank $2$ matrix with $A^2 = 0$.

At last, let's turn to the proof. Let's first see that 2. and 3. are equivalent. On the one hand, suppose that $A = BP$ for $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ satisfying $B^T = -B$ and $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ satisfying $P^2 = P^T = P$, $r(P)=1$, and $BP \neq 0$. Since $P$ is a rank $1$ matrix, we can write $P = ww^T$ for $w$ any unit vector spanning the $1$-dimensional subspace $R(P)$. Then $A = BP = Bww^T = vw^T$, where $v := Bw \neq 0$ since $A = BP \neq 0$ and where $v^T w = 0$ since
$$
 v^T w = (Bw)^T w = w^T B^T w = -w^T B w = -w^T v = -v^T w.
$$
On the other hand, suppose that $A = vw^T$ for non-zero $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $v^Tw = 0$. Then we can write $A = BP$ for $B = vw^T-wv^T$ and $P = \frac{1}{\|w\|^2}ww^T$, which satisfy our requirements.

Finally, let's turn to the very heart of the matter, the equivalence of 1. and 3. On the one hand, suppose that $A^2 = 0$ and $r(A) = 1$. Since $A$ has rank $1$, we can write it as $A = vw^T$ for $w$ any unit vector spanning the $1$-dimensional subspace $N(A)^\perp = R(A^T)$ and $v = Aw$; since $A^2 = 0$, it follows that $R(A) \subset N(A) = R(A^T)^\perp$, and hence that $v = Aw \in R(A)$ is perpendicular to $w \in R(A^T)$. On the other hand, suppose that $A = vw^T$ for non-zero $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $v^Tw = 0$. Since $w^Tv = v^Tw=0$, it follows that $A^2 = vw^Tvw^T = v(w^Tv)w^T = v0w^T = 0$; since $A = vw^T$, it follows that $R(A) = \operatorname{Span}\{v\}$, so that $r(A) = 1$.

**ADDENDUM:** If you're interested in the general case, here's what's going on:

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Then $A^2 = 0$ if and only if $A = \sum_{i=1}^{k} v_i w_i^T$, where $v_1,\dots,v_k,w_1,\dots,w_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_k\} \subset \{w_1,\dotsc,w_k\}^\perp$.

On the one hand, suppose that $A = \sum_{i=1}^{k} v_i w_i^T$, where $v_1,\dots,v_k,w_1,\dots,w_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_k\} \subset \{w_1,\dotsc,w_k\}^\perp$. Then, by our choice of the $v_i$ and $w_j$,
$$
 A^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^k v_i w_i^T\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^k v_j w_j^T\right) = \sum_{i,j=1}^k v_i w_i^T v_j w_j^T = \sum_{i,j=1}^k v_i (w_i^T v_j) w_j^T = \sum_{i,j=1}^k v_i 0 w_j^T = 0.
$$
On the other hand, suppose that $A^2 = 0$, so that $R(A) \subset N(A)$; observe that by the rank-nullity theorem, $r(A) \leq n - r(A)$, and hence $r(A) \leq n/2$. Choose an orthonormal basis $\{w_1,\dotsc,w_{r(A)}\}$ for $N(A)^\perp = R(A^T)$, so that the orthogonal projection of any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ onto $N(A)^\perp$ is
$$
 \operatorname{Proj}_{N(A)^\perp}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{r(A)} w_i w_i^T x.
$$
Then, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
 Ax = A\operatorname{Proj}_{N(A)^\perp}(x) = A\sum_{i=1}^{r(A)} w_i w_i^Tx = \sum_{i=1}^{r(A)}(Aw_i)w_i^Tx,
$$
so that $A = \sum_{i=1}^{r(A)} v_i w_i^T$ for $v_i := Aw_i$, where
$$
 \{v_1,\dotsc,v_{r(A)}\} \subset R(A) \subset (N(A)^\perp)^\perp = \{w_1,\dotsc,w_{r(A)}\}^\perp
$$
as required.

This now gives you a complete algorithm for constructing any square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $A^2 = 0$:

1. Choose $k$ vectors $w_1,\dotsc,w_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $k \leq n/2$.
2. Find $k$ vectors $v_1,\dotsc,v_k \in \{w_1,\dotsc,w_k\}^\perp$.
3. Set $A = \sum_{i=1}^k v_k w_k^\perp$.

In particular, given any orthonormal basis $\{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, e.g., the standard basis, you can do the following:

1. Choose $k$ vectors $e_{i_1},\dotsc,e_{i_k}$ from the orthonormal basis, where $k \leq n/2$.
2. Choose $k$ vectors $v_1,\dotsc,v_k \in \operatorname{Span}\{e_j \mid j \notin \{i_1,\dotsc,i_k\}\}$.
3. Set $A = \sum_{j=1}^k v_j e_{i_j}^T$.

Indeed, a closer look at the proof above shows that *every* $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $A^2 = 0$ can be constructed in this refined way.

Comment: @Braninir Thank you Branimir for the answer..  I rethink it tomorrow..

Comment: Now I would present such **algorithmic** way of construction the  matrix $A$  

1. Take any matrix $A_{n{\times}n}$.
2. Put zeros on the diagonal.
3. Leave columns with indices $r,s,t....$ and put zeros on the rest.
4. Assign zeros to $r,s,t....$ rows.

By these steps we are guaranteed that appropriate scalar products are zeros. Probably the highest possible rank of matrix $A$ is  $n/2$.   The more columns we leave the more zero rows in the matrix.

Comment: I've added the general case as an addendum, including a completely general algorithm for constructing square matrices $A$ such that $A^2 = 0$ that generalises and conceptually explains your proposed construction.

Comment: Very impressive. Your answer inspires me for new questions but before I ask them I have to think them over.